# Alfresco process service with Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle, alfresco, oracle-adf, activiti, alfresco-enterprise

I need a quick help. Is it possible to embed Alfresco process service with Oracle ADF? If so how can we do that? Is there any blog about using Alfresco BPM with Oracle ADF? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what Oracle ADF is, but Activiti is just a Java app. Therefore if Oracle ADF has an API that can be accessed from Java (for example, through REST) then you can work with it from Activiti.

Beyond that you are going to have to provide specifics on exactly what you've tried, what error you are seeing, and what, exactly, you need help with.